# How can I integrate Excel with Google Search? <VBA code>

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome

Goal: get phone numbers in Google trough a table of companies data in Excel

Table: Accounts
Name|Industry|State|City

Hit Combination of Cells and "landline phone"  on Google Search and collect in Excel

I'm making this manually. Would love to make it happen trough programing.

Tips and reference coding would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a set of topics on which you wish to do a google search.  Place the topics in column **A**:

[image]

The following macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = 1 To N
            .FollowHyperlink Address:="https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

will open a set of Google search windows.  All you need to do is add to the code to:

1. select the appropriate link
2. gather data from the web pages.

Comment: Great! Many thanks my friend. Do you have any coding reference for these 2 next steps?